# perl: symbol lookup error: libXrender.so.1: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest

Tags: c++, linux, perl

I am installing Term::Readline::Gnu cpan package in RHL5 platform. The build is properly done but while running make test I am facing the following error in t/callback.t :

> perl: symbol lookup error: perl/5.20.2/ext/lib/libXrender.so.1: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest

I have done some initial checks to find out the root cause.

```
# ldd -d -r libXrender.so.1 => no undefined symbol

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
libX11.so.6 => [proper X11 library path]
libxcb.so.1 => [proper Xcb library path]
libXau.so.6 => [proper Xau library path]
libXdmcp.so.6 => [proper Xdmcp library path]
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7dc70000
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7c6b000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00824000)
```

Library paths are not standard path like /usr/lib

```
# readelf -a  libXrender.so.1 | grep "_XGetRequest"
00009e2c  00003107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   _XGetRequest
 49: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _XGetRequest
113: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _XGetRequest
```

`readelf -a libXrender.so.1 | grep RPATH`
    Proper X11 library path is present.

I have found that libX11.so.6 contains that symbol.

My question is :

Though the X11 library path is properly placed in RPATH of libXrender, why it is not finding the sybmol?

Again, when I am setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable with proper x11 library path, the test is passing. I have also tried with -rdynamic option for dynamic loading and also maintained proper library path ordering at the link stage, but no use.

Comment: `# yum install perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu` .... The package perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu is in the EPEL repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL : Provides version 1.17a . If you are installing a later version : Skip the test. No '`make test`' was used in the available RPMS, e.g. perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.28 .